# django erasing duplicate values of a model

Tags: django, model, duplicates

Hi a have 2 models in my django apps:

```
class City(models.Model)
    name = Model.CharField(max_length=100)
    code = Model.PositiveSmallIntegerfield(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code

class Patient(models.Model)
    name = Model.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = Model.ForeignKey(City,on_delete=Model.CASCADE,null=True)
```

The problem is i had accidentally add duplicate `cities`, now i am updating the model for `code` to `unique=True`, but it's asking me to delete `Patient` instances related to those duplicate values.

Is there any way to migrate the model properly, without losing related `Patient` instances? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) to clear any duplicate values.

Comment: well migration failed with a message saying `UNIQUE constraint failed: clinic_city.code`

Comment: Before launching migration you should change duplicate code in database.

Comment: Yes I changed the 'code' attribute of the 'City' class like that: `code = Model.PositiveSmallIntegerField(unique= True)` then ran the migration